# Coalesce Mysql Datatable serverside

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datatables

I want to display all product data on the mainproduk linked in the rincian_order table, but if there is no linked product data in the rincian_order table I want to keep displaying it by filling the 'omzet' as 0, I enter the code "coalesce (sum(rincian_order.jumlah_pc)/6), 0) as omzet" it as a turnover, but such code is wrong, can anybody help?

> Error Number: 1054 Unknown column '0)' in 'field list'

```
    $this->datatables->select("mainproduk.id as id_m,mainproduk.barcode as barcod,mainproduk.nomor_kemtan as nomor_kemtan,mainproduk.nama_produk as nama_produk,mainproduk.satuan as satuan,mainproduk.nama_alias as nama_alias,mainproduk.produk_jadi as produk_jadi,mainproduk.nama_alias as nama_alias,mainproduk.nama_alias as nama_alias,mainproduk.nama_alias as nama_alias,mainproduk.min_stok_kemasan as min_stok_kemasan,mainproduk.tipe_produk as tipe_produk,mainproduk.top_item as top_item,mainproduk.status as status, coalesce(sum(rincian_order.jumlah_pc)/6), 0) as omzet");
    $this->datatables->from("mainproduk");
    $this->datatables->join("rincian_order", "mainproduk.barcode = rincian_order.barcode", "left");
    $this->datatables->where("mainproduk.status =", "1");
    $this->datatables->where("rincian_order.tipe =", "po");
    $this->datatables->where("rincian_order.status !=", "canceled");
    $this->datatables->where("rincian_order.tanggal_kirim >=", "2017-11-01");
    $this->datatables->where("rincian_order.tanggal_kirim <=", "2018-04-30");
    $this->datatables->group_by("mainproduk.id");
    $this->db->order_by("mainproduk.id", "ASC");
    $this->datatables->add_column("view", "<a href='editproduk/$1'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit' aria-hidden='true'></span></a> | <a href='logproduk/$1'><span class='fa fa-fw fa-history'></span></a>", "id_m");

    return $this->datatables->generate();
```

I managed to use the code below before, but it did not work on datatable serverside

```
SELECT mainproduk.id as id,
    mainproduk.barcode as barcod,
    mainproduk.nama_produk,
    mainproduk.nama_alias,
    mainproduk.satuan,
    mainproduk.produk_jadi,
    mainproduk.kemasan,
    mainproduk.min_stok_kemasan,
    mainproduk.status,
    mainproduk.top_item,
    mainproduk.tipe_produk,
    mainproduk.nomor_kemtan,
    coalesce(sum(R.jumlah_pc),0) as omzet
    FROM mainproduk
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT id,barcode, jumlah_pc
        FROM rincian_order WHERE tipe='po' AND status!='canceled' AND tanggal_kirim BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2018-04-30'
    ) AS R
        ON mainproduk.barcode = R.barcode WHERE status=1 GROUP BY mainproduk.id ORDER BY mainproduk.id ASC
```

my controller

```
function json() {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $this->ceklisqc_model->json();
}
```

my script datatables serverside

```
    $(function () {

    $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function(oSettings)
    {
      return {
        "iStart": oSettings._iDisplayStart,
        "iEnd": oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
        "iLength": oSettings._iDisplayLength,
        "iTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
        "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
        "iPage": Math.ceil(oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength),
        "iTotalPages": Math.ceil(oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength)
      };
    };

    var t = $("#example1").dataTable({
      initComplete: function() {
        var api = this.api();
        $('#example1_filter input')
        .off('.DT')
        .on('keyup.DT', function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            api.search(this.value).draw();
          }
        });
      },
      oLanguage: {
        sProcessing: "loading..."
      },
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: {"url": "json", "type": "POST"},
      columns: [
        {
          "data": "id_m",
          "orderable": false
        },
        {"data": "barcod"},
        {"data": "nomor_kemtan"},
        {"data": "nama_produk"},
        {"data": "satuan"},
        {"data": "nama_alias"},
        {"data": "produk_jadi"},
        {"data": "omzet"},
        {"data": "nama_alias"},
        {"data": "nama_alias"},
        {"data": "min_stok_kemasan"},
        {"data": "tipe_produk"},
        {"data": "top_item"},
        {"data": "status"},
        {"data": "view"}
      ],
      order: [[1, 'asc']],
        rowCallback: function(row, data, iDisplayIndex) {
          var info = this.fnPagingInfo();
          var page = info.iPage;
          var length = info.iLength;
          var index = page * length + (iDisplayIndex + 1);
          $('td:eq(0)', row).html(index);
        }
    });        
});
```

Comment: the query I used before was successful, you can see the query, if the code I am currently using is wrong, can you help

Comment: what is your CI version and what kind of datatable library r u using ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a small typo in your select statement.  Change this:

```
coalesce(sum(rincian_order.jumlah_pc)/6), 0) as omzet
```

to this:

```
coalesce(sum(rincian_order.jumlah_pc) / 6, 0) as omzet
```

I had originally commented that because you are grouping by `mainproduk.id` but selecting many non aggregate columns, your query is invalid.  I recant saying this, because it actually looks like the other columns are all from the same table *and* that `mainproduk.id` is the primary key for the `mainproduk` table, in which case what you are doing is valid.

Comment: A new error message appears 
Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as omzet

Comment: @MochamadNurkhayalKadafi I don't know Codeigniter.  Is it allowed to have raw SQL in the `select()` call?  If not, then you might have to use a raw query here.

Comment: can you help me how?

Comment: Can you reply to my comment please?

Comment: for your question, I do not think so, but have no way other than using coalesce, I feel confused

Comment: Yes, you do have a choice.  Just select `SUM(rincian_order.jumlah_pc) / 6`, and then handle the `NULL` case in your PHP code.  If you can't select `SUM(something)` either, then you're using the wrong API and you should be using a raw query.

Comment: my question i have update. I've tried to use "sum (details_order.jumlah_pc) / 6 as omzet" and it works, and how next if unrelated data in detail_order table is still displayed?

Comment: I don't understand your comment unfortunately.

Comment: Earlier you in the previous comment, well that's how, I do not know.
Because I want to keep displaying data even if there is not connected in rincian_order table

Comment: `how next if unrelated data in detail_order table is still displayed?` ... what does this mean?

Comment: I mean if there is no data product that is not connected in rincian_order table I want to keep displaying it with 'omzet' it as '0', if coalesce on my code is deleted then data product that is not connected will not show, while using coalesce in my code above can not.

Comment: can you help me, i feel confused @TimBiegeleisen